# Java based web application using Node.js?

Tags: java, web-applications, node.js

I am a novice to web application programming trying to build first webapp and read that Node.js can be used for high-performance, highly concurrent and suited for web applications.

My question is that is it possible to hook up Node.js with Java backend?
How does that work?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start off with node.js is a backend. So if you have a misconception of what node.js then you don't need Java.

If you want to integrated node.js into an existing Java application to use it as a real time communication platform then you can get the two talking to each other over TCP sockets.

Take a look [at the `net` docs](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.7/api/net.html)